# How to remove all lines in a file containing a string from another file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I want to remove all lines in a file containing a string from another file. So I don't want to remove the lines which are identical, there are none, but remove all lines if they share a string from another file. And write the lines which didn't contain a string from the other file to a new file. Example:

File A:

```
bird, snake
dog, cat
rabbit,fox
eagle,dove
```

File B:

```
dog
dove
```

RESULT File:

```
bird,snake
rabbit,fox
```

Please help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The best method to use depends on the sizes of both files. Are both files (potentially) (tens of) thousands of lines, or only file A?

Answer (score 6):

Use the following `grep` expression:

```
grep -vFf file_B file_A
```

Here is a test:

```
$ cat file_A 
bird, snake
dog, cat
rabbit,fox
eagle,dove

$ cat file_B 
dog
dove

$ grep -vFf file_B file_A 
bird, snake
rabbit,fox
```

- `-f` will read the patterns from a file (one per line), `file_B` in this case
- `-F` will consider the patterns read from `file_B` as fixed string, meaning no further pattern operation will be done on the patterns
- `-v` will print the non-matching lines i.e. the lines of `file_A` that does not contain the petterns from `file_B`.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. In that test it is working. But if I test it with bigger files, for example 20k lines it is not working correctly. Its not removing every line it should do. Maybe half of them or less. Whats wrong?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the contents of the actual file....could you provide some actual example lines where this is failing?

Comment: Just a list of first names for example. With 10 it is working. With 10k not.

Comment: If its still not working, please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/608903/edit) your question and add some actual file contents from both files where this is not working..

Comment: @JacobVlijm Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22825/discussion-between-muru-and-jacob-vlijm).